# Why is it not possible to reassign the value in the contract level in solidity?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, ether

This is my code,
I want to know the reason why I am not able to change the value in the variable a.
Would you please give me the reason or any information from solidity doc?

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract simple {
    uint public a = 3;
    a = 16; // error occurred : parser Error expected identifier but got '='
    }
```

Comment: Did you already tried / checked this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/solidity-variables/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the data in the declarative part of the contract code. Put the change in the contract constructor or function.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;

contract simple
{
    uint public a = 3;

    constructor()
    {
      a = 16; 
    }

    function changeData() public
    {
      a = 16;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a function within a contract to modify values. You can achieve this by declaring the function as `view` type. E.g.

```
contract Demo {

    uint number;

    function set(uint _number) public {
        number = _number + 1;
    }
}
```